# Projection of rational normal scroll

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am looking at the classification of degree $d$ nondegenerate projective surface in $\mathbb{P}^d$. (See Theorem 8 in https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kjm/1250776405).

One kind of such surfaces consists of projections of minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{d+1}$ from a point out side of the surface. (Minimal surfaces are also classified in the same paper, they are cones over rational normal curve, rational normal scrolls or the Veronese surface).

Let $S$ be a surface of minimal surface(degree $d$) in $\mathbb{P}^{d+1}$(assume it is not the Veronese surface), let $\pi$ be the projection from a point outside of $S$, so that $\pi(S)$ is of degree $d$.

My question is: what does $\pi(S)$ look like?

All I know $\pi(S)$ is a projective surface which can be singular. In fact it was proved in the above paper that $\pi(S)$ can be not normal and in that case the singular locus is a line.

I hope to obtain more info on $\pi(S)$ what we know on $S$ itself. In particular, I am interested in the following things:
1. when $S$ is a cone, it $\pi(S)$ is a cone (of some sort)?

2. When $S$ is a scroll, what is the image of a line?

Thanks!